# how to set small and big icon for gcm notification when using notification payload

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using **GCM 9.4.0**. As the official doc of GCM, when using notificaiton payload,GCM handle notifications by itself,and notification messaging only has one parameter:icon for small icon.

so,how to set both small and big icon? Thanks for help.

Comment: AFAIK, FCM doesn't have an API to set a large-icon and so is with GCM since FCM is the new version of GCM which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure. You may want to check this [GitHub post](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/4) and [a related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774841/fcm-gcm-json-payload-how-to-specify-a-large-icon/41785773#41785773) for additional insights.

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
Notification notification=notificationBuilder.build();
notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(android.R.id.icon, R.drawable.your_large_icon);
```

or

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_small_icon);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_96px_large_icon);
builder.setLargeIcon(bm);
```

Comment: when using notification payload, gcm handled by itself. and gcm din't offer interface to change notification style.

Comment: @AlanWang could you try it with FCM since GCM is now deprecated and use data payload instead of notification payload

Comment: For some reasons, i have to use GCM and notification payload.Data payload dosen't have this problem.And FCM handled notification payload by itself as GCM.